# downgrade gcc to 3.9 or less in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, gcc

I have been trying to downgrade `gcc` to 3.9 or lesser but I can downgrade it to only till 4.4 and the error I'm getting while using `sudo apt-get install gcc-3.0` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-3.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-3.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-3.0'
```

Comment: `gcc` version 4.0.0 was released April 20, 2005.  There was no version 3.9; the highest 3.x I see on GNU's gcc version page is 3.4.6 (March 6, 2006). https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html & https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline  Either way you're talking about something very old; are you sure of your versions.

Comment: yes, sir. The code i want to run is of 2008 and the latest gcc is throwing me an error. gcc-4.4 is just throwing me 2 errors so i figured it was the problem with the gcc compiler, i tried installing gcc less then 4.4 but im not able to. Is there any easier way to install gcc less then 4.4 or 3.4.6. Thank you

Comment: Why not fix your c-code instead ?

Comment: I am not much of a programmer, but i tried and messed things up more therefore my only option was to run the previous written code.